# Is it possible to create a portal larger than 2x3 to the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can one create a fully functional 3x3 portal? (That's 3x3 on the inside, and 5x5 on the outside)

If you're wondering why I would want to do such a thing, it's purely for aesthetic reasons. I have a room with a wall 3 wide built deep within my base and it would be more trouble than it is worth to resize the room. Hence a 3x3 portal would be perfect.

Comment: Portals to nether are 2x3, **but** if you have the [Enhanced Portals](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1301217-1467spmplan-enhanced-portals-2nd-jan-horizontal-portals/) mod, you can make portals of any size; i.e.
1x1,
5x10,
1x2, and so on.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of [snapshot 13w37a](https://mojang.com/2013/09/minecraft-snapshot-13w37a/), you can now create portals of **any size** between 2x3 and 21x21. This is a feature in Minecraft 1.7.

Answer (score 11):

As of Minecraft 1.5_01, only 2x3 portals can be created (via Obsidian frames) to provide transport to the nether.

Comment: darn! I guess I'll just have to go to work remodeling my house.

Answer (score 9):

You can use inventory hackers to give yourself some portal blocks (data value 90) to place down, seeing as it gives you no advantage *as such* it's not *really* cheating...

Comment: Portal blocks not inside a frame and not touching other portal blocks will despawn as soon as they receive a block update, apparently. The result is that you can place (and use!) a single portal block just fine, but as soon as you place a second beside it the first despawns (because at least one of its other sides is non-obsidian, non-portal), and the despawning of the first is a block update so the second immediately despawns. Consequently, creative mode and inventory hacks that give you placeable portal blocks only let you create 1x1 portals.

Answer (score 3):

According to what I know, the 1.7 update allows you to build a portal at any size, but it can't be any smaller than 3x2. So, you can make a Square 3x3 portal, If that's what you're talking about. if you have a 23x23 room, internal space. then you will be able to build the maximum internal space portal, 21x21 internal space

Comment: This just repeats what 3ventic's answer says.

Answer (score -2):

You can hand-place portal blocks (not the obsidian frame, but the actual purple portal blocks) using [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/), which is an external world editor. By hand-placing them, you can make a portal of any shape and size.

Comment: You should offer more information. How would one do it with MCEdit?

Comment: @3ventic I fixed it to say what they should have said.

Comment: Well, really it's not hand placing, you have to use mc edits external program to do it, if you're going to use a mod/program I'd just use TMI or NEI to spawn the block into your inventory EDIT: Doesn't work, block update, I forgot. Still, getting enhanced portals would be easier than getting mcedit if you'll only use it once